# unity shader cannot show in mobile

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I copy a shader from here: http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/star/

I find that the final "star" shows perfectly in Unity Editor, but it cannot be shown in Android platform. The shader is as follow:

```
Shader "Star" {
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                struct data {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    fixed4 color: COLOR;
                };

                data vert (data v) {
                    v.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    return v;
                }

                fixed4 frag(data f) : COLOR {
                    return f.color;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: i dont have time to go through the tutorial, but it says right at the start that its made for Unity 3, there also is a star tutorial for unity4 that does it a bit differently.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the unity4 one, still no luck.

Comment: Old question, the shader looks fine. Maybe it’s a good old “Shader not included in a built “ problem. It has to be used on some material in a scene or placed in resources, or added to a list of always included shaders.